# "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'a' looking for beginning of value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an IAM policy with the below code

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "s3-replication" {
  name = "${var.servicename}-${var.environment}-${var.region}-storage-replication"
  role = aws_iam_role.s3-replication.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        ${local.replication_source_bucket_arn}, 
        ${local.replication_source_bucket_arn}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ReplicateObject",
        "s3:ReplicateDelete",
        "s3:ReplicateTags",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${local.replication_destination_bucket_arn}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

and I have declared the local variables like this

```
create_backup_bucket               = contains(keys(var.backup_region), var.region) ? 1 : 0
replication_source_bucket_arn      = local.create_backup_bucket == 1 || var.recovery_pipeline == "false" ? aws_s3_bucket.notes-broker-storage.0.arn : aws_s3_bucket.notes-broker-storage-replica.0.arn
replication_destination_bucket_arn = local.create_backup_bucket == 1 ? aws_s3_bucket.notes-broker-storage-backup.0.arn : aws_s3_bucket.notes-broker-storage-replica[0].arn
```

variables.tf

```
variable "backup_region" {
  type        = map(any)

  default = {
    eu-west-1 = "eu-west-3"
    eu-west-2 = "eu-south-2"
  }
}
```

I notice an error in my pipeline saying "policy contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'a' looking for beginning of value"

```
│   85:   policy = <<POLICY
│   86: {
│   87:   "Version": "2012-10-17",
│   88:   "Statement": [
│   89:     {
│   90:       "Action": [
│   91:         "s3:Get*",
│   92:         "s3:ListBucket"
│   93:       ],
│   94:       "Effect": "Allow",
│   95:       "Resource": [
│   96:         ${local.replication_source_bucket_arn}, 
│   97:         ${local.replication_source_bucket_arn}/*"
│   98:       ]
│   99:     },
│  100:     {
│  101:       "Action": [
│  102:         "s3:ReplicateObject",
│  103:         "s3:ReplicateDelete",
│  104:         "s3:ReplicateTags",
│  105:         "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
│  106:       ],
│  107:       "Effect": "Allow",
│  108:       "Resource": [
│  109:         "${local.replication_destination_bucket_arn}/*"
│  110:       ]
│  111:     }
│  112:   ]
│  113: }
```

Where in the S3 bucket ARN is not getting populated. The plan output works for us-east-2 region by populating the right S3 ARN but fails for us-east-1. Can someone help me figure out why this discrepancy ?

Comment: I think the error is on lines 96 and 97: ${local.replication_source_bucket_arn}, ${local.replication_source_bucket_arn}/*". This should be `local.replication_source_bucket_arn` and `"${local.replication_source_bucket_arn}/*"` respectively.

Comment: Agreed those are the typos in the template.

Answer (score 0):

For generating a policy document dynamically based on data from elsewhere in your Terraform configuration, it's better to use [`jsonencode`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode) with a normal Terraform value as the argument, and then Terraform can be the one to worry about generating valid JSON syntax and all you need to worry about is producing a data structure of the expected shape.

For example:

```
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "s3:Get*",
          "s3:ListBucket",
        ]
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = [
          local.replication_source_bucket_arn,
          "${local.replication_source_bucket_arn}/*",
        ]
      },
      # (I'll leave the second statement as an exercise;
      # the structure will be similar to the above.)
    ]
  })
```

Refer to the `jsonencode` documentation for a table of how the function translates Terraform's data types into JSON's data types when encoding.